# TypeScript error Cannot read property 'REPOSITORY' of undefined

Tags: javascript, oop, typescript

New to TypeScript (but not to OO Design) I don't understand what happens

file application.ts

```
class
    APPLICATION{

        constructor(){
            console.log("constructor APPLICATION")
            this.database = new REPOSITORY
        }

        database: REPOSITORY
}

new APPLICATION

import { REPOSITORY } from "./repository"
```

file repository.ts

```
export

class
    REPOSITORY {

        constructor() {
            console.log("constructor de REPOSITORY")
        }

}
```

ANd I get the error

```
    this.database = new repository_1.REPOSITORY;
                                    ^
```

TypeError: Cannot read property 'REPOSITORY' of undefined
    at new APPLICATION (Z:\Documents\Phi\Developpement\TypeScript\test\application.js:6:41)

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 2):

You are perfectly right !
I thought that the compiler was in two-passes and that the order of these statements were not imposed.
As I think that this import/export mecanism should be automatic, I would prefer to hide it at the end of the code ! Too bad !

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your `import` statement for `REPOSITORY` occurs after `REPOSITORY` is used in the constructor for `APPLICATION`, which means that it is not yet defined in the constructor (the variable assignment resulting from the import statement is not hoisted). You will need to import prior to use:

```
import { REPOSITORY } from "./repository"

class APPLICATION {
    constructor(){
        console.log("constructor APPLICATION")
        this.database = new REPOSITORY();
    }
    database: REPOSITORY
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe imports are hoisted.  Try moving `import { REPOSITORY } from "./repository"` up in your code.